# Deleting records with no content

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where I keep track of email subscriptions. I have code that successfully adds and removes subscription records. I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete records with no subscriptions. Here is an example:

```
{_id: "subscr-01@gmail.com"
    {subscriber: {product-1: true}, {product-2: true} }.
    {publisher: {product-1: true}
}
```

I know how to remove a subscription.

```
 query: {_id: "subscr-01@gmail.com"}
update: {"$unset" "publisher.product-1": {"$exists": true} }
```

And if that leaves the sub-document empty, I know how to find and remove that (albeit in a second API call... would love to know if there is a way to make the update and the sub-document delete both happen in one API call).

```
query: {_id: "subscr-01@gmail.com", "publisher": {} }"
update: {"$unset": {"publisher": {} }
```

Here's my immediate question: After all is said and done, it is possible for me to end up with email addresses in the collection that have no fields (no sub-documents).

```
{_id: "subscr-01@gmail.com"}
```

How do I find and delete these "empty" records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the documents where the `subscriber` and `publisher` fields aren't present, you'd want to create a query that checks for the existence of those fields. The filter would look like this:

```
{
    "subscriber": { $exists: false },
    "publisher": { $exists: false }
}
```

If you want to delete all the documents that match this filter you would use [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/).

Comment: Thank you. My concern is for the future. I could have other fields that are added to a record, so I am really looking for the general case: find and delete records with zero fields - without necessarily knowing the names of all the fields that could ever be added to a record (e.g. a schemaless database like Mongo). The solution you suggest will delete the record when those two specific fileds are missing but that might delete a record that has other fields. It is important to me to solve the problem for the more general case. I welcome your further thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41927382/13878071) that could be useful. If you pass that filter to `deleteMany` then you will delete all documents that only have an `_id` field.

Comment: Thank you. This worked (from the answer you pointed to)
`db.collection.deleteMany({ "$where": "return Object.keys(this).length == 1" })`